# Error installing provider "aws": Get https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-aws/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: terraform

I'm getting this:

```
Error installing provider "aws": Get https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-aws/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

when I do a `terraform init`.

It seems the SSL certificate in use by our proxy is signed by an unknown authority.

Is there a way of disabling the check?

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15713#issuecomment-319980198

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15713#issuecomment-334023168

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ZScaler please try to disable it

Answer (score 0):

try these steps, they helped me:

```
Add zscaler cert to the Linux to avoid network issues:
- Export Zscaler Root CA cert .cer with base64 encoding
- Copy that .cer file to /usr/locals/share/ca-certificates of your machine
- In "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates" run:
-- sudo openssl x509 -inform PEM -n xxx.cer -out xxx.crt
-- sudo update-ca-certificates
```

After this described error was fixed in my (Linux) machine.

Answer (score -2):

Please upgrade Go to the latest version since it was causing this issue with Terraform. This should resolve your problem.